# Lambda Expression +IEnumerable+ C#+ Where+Contains

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause, ienumerable

In C#, I have an `IEnumerable<Data>` named `items`
And `Data` is a class that contains 3 string Attributes.

I want to get all items that attribute1 contains a string

```
public IEnumerable<Data> getDataFiltered(IEnumerable<Data> items,string Filter)
{
    return items.Where(item=>item.Attribute1.Contains(Filter));
}
```

It throws an exception, however when I use:

```
public IEnumerable<Data> getDataFiltered(IEnumerable<Data> items,string Filter)
{
    return items.Where(item=>item.Attribute1==Filter);
}
```

It works.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also actively filter out the results that have a null value for Attribute1

```
return items.Where(i => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Attribute1) && i.Attribute1.Contains(filter));
```

When you create a variable of a type, unless you specify a value, it will have the default value for the type. There are two types in .NET reference types and value types. The default value for references types (anything created as a class) is null. A string is an example of a reference type.

```
public class Data
{
    public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
    public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
    public string Attribute3 { get; set; }
}
```

The code above, all three attribute values are not initialized and have a value of NULL. To assign a value to the three attributes when create a new instance of your object with 'new Data()' you can create a constructor that assigns a value.

```
public Data()
{
    Attribute1 = Attribute2 = Attribute3 = String.Empty();
}
```

Now all attributes will have the empty string value. Meaning they are initialized but don't have a value.

Value types (anything defined as a struct) can not be NULL. Examples of this are `DateTime`, `int`, `double`, `decimal`, etc. The default value for number types is 0. The default value for `DateTime` is `DateTime.MinValue`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the value of Attribute1 was null then calling .Contains will crash and == will not.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your `Attribute1`s are probably null.

You can't call `Contains` on `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Consdider this:

```
public IEnumerable<Data> getDataFiltered(IEnumerable<Data> items, string Filter){

    return items.Where(item => item != null && item.Contains(Filter));
}
```

I added the nullity checks to make sure that `Contains` isn't called on null reference. `String` is a reference type which means that it can occasionaly be null.

Comment: It isn't likely that the objects in the collection are null (though possible), it is more likely that the Property has not been initialized.

Comment: @NerdFury: you're right, I think I misinterpreted the code sample

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for the exact value use == if you want to check for the occurence of a string use either of the following.

For a case sensitive approach the following :-

```
items.Where(item => (item ?? "").Contains(Filter));
```

?? is the coalesc operator in c# just like sql's ie the first non value

Contains however is case sensitive so if this is not desired then the following might be what you want.

```
items.Where(item => -1 != (item ?? "").IndexOf(Filter, StringComparison .InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```